# Resource folder selection not working as expected

Tags: android, image, layout, resources

I've a large image logo I'm currently scaling (usually down) to fill 50% of screen. At first I placed it in the base /res/drawable folder. It worked fine for most devices, but on some low-end phones with small screens the scaling introduced aliasing and it looks horrible. So I distributed the images as follows:

```
    /res/drawable   
        -Large image, intended to be used on most devices
    /res/drawable-normal
        -Smaller image, intended to target smaller screens
```

However, when testing on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10' it picks the image in normal folder instead of the image in the base drawable folder. I know this tablet fits in the drawable-xlarge category since it is picking other resources from there. So I had to come up with this directory structure for the thing to work:

```
    /res/drawable   
        -Large image, intended to be used on most devices
    /res/drawable-normal
        -Smaller image, intended to target smaller screens
    /res/drawable-xlarge
        -Same image as the drawable base folder, only used for the tablet to select the correct image.
```

Now it works as I want, but I can't understand why the system selects the normal folder for an xlarge device. Shouldn't it look first in the xlarge folder and then fallback on the base drawable folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It falls back in a scaleable manner. Obviously if it can't find Xlarge, then large is a closer match then normal is a closer match then the default folder..

Comment: @Blundell you might want to post your comment as an answer, so that it can be marked as solved.

Comment: Thought someone might have wanted to give a bit more detail so just left it as a comment :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It falls back in a scaleable manner.

If it can't find Xlarge, then large is a closer match then normal is a closer match then the default folder

Reference:

[How Android finds best matching resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)

[Android.Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#Compatibility)

[image]
[image]